# Как установить data-widget="collapse" изначально открытым?

Tags: html, bootstrap

как установить data-widget="collapse" изначально открытым, по дефолту он закрыт, в документации не нашел

Answer (score 0):

расворачиваемый блок должен иметь два класса:

```
.collapse.show
```

а у триггера свойство:

```
aria-expanded="true"
```

Comment: получилось, но теперь не скрывает его обратно

Comment: а js файлы подключили (bootstrap) ? нужно смотреть в Dev tools браузера работает ли при клике там хоть что нибудь

Comment: Да уже на обычный js переписал)